# Is there a way to run an svg on click?

Tags: javascript, svg

```
<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"width="450px" height="450px" viewBox="0 0 450 450" style="enable-background:new 0 0 450 450;" xml:space="preserve">
            <style type="text/css">
                .st0{fill:#FFFFFF;}
                .st1{fill:none;stroke:#000000;stroke-miterlimit:10;}
            </style>
            <rect id="1" x="299.8" y="300.5" class="st0" width="149.5" height="150.5"/>
            <rect id="2" x="150.2" y="300.5" class="st0" width="149.5" height="150.5"/>
            <rect id="3" y="300.5" class="st0" width="149.5" height="150.5"/>
            <rect id="4" x="299.8" y="150.5" class="st0" width="149.5" height="150.5"/>
            <rect id="5" x="150.2" y="150.5" class="st0" width="149.5" height="150.5"/>
            <rect id="6" y="150.5" class="st0" width="149.5" height="150.5"/>
            <rect id="7" x="299.8" class="st0" width="149.5" height="150.5"/>
            <rect id="8" x="150.2" class="st0" width="149.5" height="150.5"/>
            <rect id="9" class="st0" width="149.5" height="150.5"/>
            <line class="path" fill="none" stroke="#000000" x1="149.5" y1="0" x2="149.5" y2="450"/>
            <line class="path" fill="none" stroke="#000000" x1="299.5" y1="450" x2="299.5" y2="0"/>
            <line class="path" fill="none" stroke="#000000" x1="0" y1="150.5" x2="450" y2="150.5"/>
            <line class="path" fill="none" stroke="#000000" x1="450" y1="300.5" x2="0" y2="300.5"/>
        </svg>
```

I have this svg which is a tic tac toe board. I want it to load(run the animation of the line tags) AFTER the user enters the number of players and player names. Is there a way to do that? the rect elements are what I will use to target areas while playing the game.

```
.path {
  stroke-dasharray: 1000;
  stroke-dashoffset: 1000;
  animation: dash 5s linear forwards;
}

@keyframes dash {
  to {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }
}
```

Comment: What animation of the line tags is that? There's lots of different ways to animate and any answer would depend on which one you're using.

Comment: Sorry, the reply button doesnt let me format. The path class draws the lines

Comment: right now that animation runs on load. I want it to run after I click ok in a prompt box. Im not sure how to connect the two

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like so perhaps i.e. set the class on click?

```js
function run() {
  var lines = document.getElementsByTagName("line");
  for (var i = 0; i < lines.length; i++) {
    lines[i].setAttribute("class", "path");
  }
}
```

```css
line {
  stroke-dasharray: 1000;
  stroke-dashoffset: 1000;
}

.path {
  animation: dash 5s linear forwards;
}

@keyframes dash {
  to {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<button onclick="run()">click me</button>
<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"width="450px" height="450px" viewBox="0 0 450 450" style="enable-background:new 0 0 450 450;" xml:space="preserve">
            <style type="text/css">
                .st0{fill:#FFFFFF;}
                .st1{fill:none;stroke:#000000;stroke-miterlimit:10;}
            </style>
            <rect id="1" x="299.8" y="300.5" class="st0" width="149.5" height="150.5"/>
            <rect id="2" x="150.2" y="300.5" class="st0" width="149.5" height="150.5"/>
            <rect id="3" y="300.5" class="st0" width="149.5" height="150.5"/>
            <rect id="4" x="299.8" y="150.5" class="st0" width="149.5" height="150.5"/>
            <rect id="5" x="150.2" y="150.5" class="st0" width="149.5" height="150.5"/>
            <rect id="6" y="150.5" class="st0" width="149.5" height="150.5"/>
            <rect id="7" x="299.8" class="st0" width="149.5" height="150.5"/>
            <rect id="8" x="150.2" class="st0" width="149.5" height="150.5"/>
            <rect id="9" class="st0" width="149.5" height="150.5"/>
            <line fill="none" stroke="#000000" x1="149.5" y1="0" x2="149.5" y2="450"/>
            <line fill="none" stroke="#000000" x1="299.5" y1="450" x2="299.5" y2="0"/>
            <line fill="none" stroke="#000000" x1="0" y1="150.5" x2="450" y2="150.5"/>
            <line fill="none" stroke="#000000" x1="450" y1="300.5" x2="0" y2="300.5"/>
        </svg>
```

Comment: Not quite. that svg animation is being triggered on load, I want to hold and trigger it at a specific time with the "ok" from the prompt box; i.e. prompt asking if the user is ready then when the user clicks "ok" button on that prompt it will trigger the svg to run at that point. adding class will rerun the svg

Comment: No, the animation is triggered when the class is added. I don't understand what you want it to look like. At the moment the grid is invisible and the animation starts to draw the grid when you click the button, if that's not what you want you need to describe more clearly what you do want.